# Neural Network Oscillates Around 0.5

Tags: neural-network, processing.js, khan-academy

I wanted to create my own neural network - mainly for the fun of it, but also because Khan Academy doesn't allow libraries, and I hadn't seen any good neural nets on the site.

**Neural Network Info:**

The one I am showing in the images is a 1-2-3-2-1 neural network, although it does this for all layer sizes and amounts. The thicker line is the first training run, which is 5,000 iterations. The thinner line shows another 1,000 iterations after the first training run.

**Training Data Info:**

I'm making it switch 0 to 1 and 1 to 0. The graphs shown are the loss when trying to change 1 to 0. The dataset looks like this:

```
[{
  inputs: [0],
  outputs: [1]
}, {
  inputs: [1],
  outputs: [0]
}]
```

Before each iteration, the dataset is randomized.

I put a neural net together, but when testing I ran across an interesting issue:
It will oscillate around 0.5 about 3/4ths of the time. The other 1/4th of the time, it works as intended. Sometimes it will go to where it is supposed to (about a quarter of the time) (These graphs show the loss, with the line in the center being 0):

[image: Image showing convergence towards 0]

Another part of the time (maybe 1/20th, so pretty rarely), it will "stick" at 0.5, but then kick itself out:
[image]

Or it'll get it right, but then just mess itself up for no reason (*very* rare, almost never happens):
[image]

And the rest of the time, it will just stay at around 0.5:
[image]

I have no clue what's causing these to happen (although I think it might be my implementation of Gradient Descent, found on line 137 of the program), or how to fix them.
You can find the program here:
[khanacademy.org/cs/-/6305674778411008](https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/-/6305674778411008)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this can be a overffitting. the neural network reach the min. but after of some time the loss start to grow again and stop in a local min.
but this depends of how you neural network are implemented. you need see if you data is normalized between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1 for example. because if o data is not normalized the gradient can "break out".
Standartzation is important too.

Comment: That would probably explain the third graph. What exactly is "normalizing the data" though? Mapping it to be between 0 and 1? I probably should have included what I was testing this with in the question (I'll edit it), but I'm making it switch 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.